# how to pass value from main query inside a sub sub sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

i want to pass a variable from main query into the sub query. it is a problem since this query uses 3 subs.

i've tried join but since i am new, its a bit confusing. the code is something like this

```
select fav.cust_id
from 
(
    select cust_id
    from
    (
        select cust_id
        from
        (
            select c.cust_id
            from customer c
        )
    )
)fav
where fav.cust_id = 12;
```

as we can see, im trying to pass the value '12' into the deepest sub query (c.cust_id) so that it return the intended values in the main query. if i try to pass the value in the first sub query, it will return wrong data as it tries to fetch all the data from the second sub query onward before using the condition. so what im trying to do is to pass the condition inside the deepest sub query so that it will filter the result from there to return the intended values.

update:
here is the close-to-real query that i made.

```
select fav.cust_lname, fav.cust_time
from
(
    select max(cust_lname), max(cust_time)
    --there is another code here for some calculations
    from
    (
         select lname cust_lname, time cust_time
         --there is another code here for some calculations
         from 
         (
              select c.cust_id
              --there is another code here for some calculations to return the cust_lname and cust_time
              from
              customer c
              where cust_g = 'MALE'
              AND cust_id = --in the original code, this is a parameter. i want this to read the value from the main query
         )
    )       
)fav,
customer_table ct

where ct.header_id = --custom parameter that im trying to play with
AND ct.cust_id = --i want to relate this with the cust_id inside the sub query
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this query can be simplified to `select 12*1 from dual;`

Comment: the inner subquery should have join with outer table. in the sample u just mentioned one table... but in reality i guess multiple tables must be there.... in that case, the inner query and table should have joining columns accordingly... in consecutive inner queries also this must be followed... try that... without proper example or tables,... we cannot frame sample query

Comment: @Tamil hye i've update the query

Answer (score 0):

The query can be simplified as give below. You dont need nested subqueries.

```
select fav.cust_id
from fav
join b
on b.cust_id = fav.cust_id
join c
on c.cust_id = b.cust_id
WHERE fav.cust_id = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

from your given query,

```
(
    select max(cust_lname), max(cust_time)
    --there is another code here for some calculations
    from
    (
         select lname cust_lname, time cust_time
         --there is another code here for some calculations
         from 
         (
              select c.cust_id
              --there is another code here for some calculations to return the cust_lname and cust_time
              from
              customer c
              where cust_g = 'MALE'
              AND cust_id = --in the original code, this is a parameter. i want this to read the value from the main query
         )
    )       
)fav
```

is the in-table query (the fetched records serves as table1 data)

the other table used is

```
customer_table ct
```

and as per your code, its like joining in table1 (fav) with second table but it is not available within the subquery.

consider this...
the code snippet used for table1 alone.... from where it will fetch the ct.cust_id??? it ct table is not within the subquery this would give invalid identifier error.

as per your given code, you trying to fetch the fav.cust_lname, fav.cust_time which are the values from a subquery by joining with cust_id from outside customer table. if this is so the requirement, then it can be written as

```
select (subquery with join from ct table) from customer_table ct
```

if you wanted to use the join in the in-table  query itself

```
select column1, column2 from (select ....cust_id... from customer_table ctin ...)fav, customer_table ct where...
```

something like this should be done i.e., that joining table should be called within the in-table query with reference to that column

the main thing is you have used in-table query with join to external table which is not available in the in-table query, either switch to subquery or have external table introduced in in-table query

Answer (score 0):

okay so i learned new things today. i used the `OUTER APPLY` to pass the value inside the deepest sub query thanks for all the suggestions.

```
select fav.cust_lname, fav.cust_time
from
customer_table ct
outer apply
(
    select max(cust_lname), max(cust_time)
    --there is another code here for some calculations
    from
    (
         select lname cust_lname, time cust_time
         --there is another code here for some calculations
         from 
         (
              select c.cust_id
              --there is another code here for some calculations to return the cust_lname and cust_time
              from
              customer c
              where cust_g = 'MALE'
              AND cust_id = ct.cust_id --match with the column in the outside query table
         )
    )       
)fav,

where ct.header_id = --custom parameter that im trying to play with
--AND ct.cust_id = --i want to relate this with the cust_id inside the sub query --removed this
```